# How to deal with modulo of $ \sum \binom{n}{r}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, modular-arithmetic

Given $ p = \binom{2562}{2019} + \binom{2562}{2021} + \binom{2562}{2023} + \binom{2562}{2025} +.... +\binom{2562}{2561}$

and  $q =\binom{p+2562}{2019} + \binom{p+2562}{2021} + \binom{p+2562}{2023} + \binom{p+2562}{2025} +.... +\binom{p+2562}{2561}$

> Find  :
>
> (i)   $\ \binom{p}{q}+\binom{q}{p}$ modulo by $2019$
>
> (ii)   $p+q$ modulo by $2019$

First of all I thinking of Lucas's Theorem ,but it seems only apply to $p$ .

What about $q$ ? It's like we working on a ton of digits.I can't solve anymore.

Some of my friends said that $p=q$ .Why do they thinking or I'm missing to interpret $p$ and $q$  ?

What are you thinking about this problem? Please tell me if it has a flaw in problem or give me some hint to modulo them (espacially $q$).   Thank you and I appreciate for any helps.

Comment: Source of this problem, please?

Comment: We need a source other than "friends", for this walks, talks and quacks like a question from a running contest.

Comment: I created this problem up by myself while reading Combinatorics lesson and have an idea to combine them for more complexity.It's not from any contest problems.

Comment: it's not hard to reduce the used numbers  for representing the problem, what's the next major difficulty ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Okay, finally the answer it might be 1 or 2 or something from definition of Lucas's Theorem, but  one more thing I want to know if we do a modulo directly to $q$ by $2019$ ,what is the result? (I just added up in edit)

Comment: If you devised your problem, then what was your basis for thinking it had a non-brute-forcey solution?

Comment: For (ii) Lucas's theorem show that we can compute $p$ modulo by $2019$ , but I'm not sure how to use Lucas's Theorem on $q$ . Sorry if I have a mistake to understand your question , I'm   beginner to an english.

Comment: translate... in browser I can translate to over 90 languages I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Help(not an answer)**

As $p+l!=p!\cdot l!\cdot {{p+l}\choose{p}}$ each term is a scaled version of  the terms for $p$ by $p!\cdot {{p+l}\choose {p}}= {{p+l}!\over l!}$